# Infinite Animation of 2 views following a quart / half circle

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I'm working on a project that required me to animate 2 views simultaneously.

**State 0 :** the 2 views are on `x1 = -Radius, y1 = 0 / x2 = Radius, y2 = 0` of a circle.

**State 1 :** they should move simultaneously to the top center of the circle and collide (like a pendulum)

**State 2 :** They should go back simultaneously to the bottom center of the circle and collide as well

**State 3 .. N :** They should go to the top center collide then go back to the  bottom center and collide again...

I have tried multiple libraries including [ArcAnimator](https://github.com/asyl/ArcAnimator) but none of them seemed to support this.

[image]

Is there any way to do that? by XML only or programmatically doesn't really matter.

Edit :

This is what I've done so far :

```
private void startAnimation () {

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager ().getDefaultDisplay ().getMetrics (metrics);

    int width   = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height  = metrics.heightPixels;
    float scale = metrics.density;

    float initLeftX         = leftBall.getX ();
    float initLeftY         = leftBall.getY ();
    float targetLeftX       = topHelperView.getX (); // helper view on top of circle.
    float targetLeftY       = topHelperView.getY (); 

    float initRightX        = rightBall.getX ();
    float initRightY        = rightBall.getY ();
    float targetRightX      = topHelperView.getX ();
    float targetRightY      = topHelperView.getY ();

    AnimatorSet animSet     = new AnimatorSet ();

    ObjectAnimator anim1    = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat (leftBall, "x", initLeftX, targetLeftX);
    ObjectAnimator anim2    = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat (leftBall, "y", initLeftY, targetLeftY);
    ObjectAnimator anim3    = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat (rightBall, "x", initRightX, targetRightX);
    ObjectAnimator anim4    = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat (rightBall, "y", initRightY, targetRightY);

    animSet.play (anim1).with (anim2).with (anim3).with (anim4);

    animSet.setDuration (5000);
    animSet.start ();

}
```

However the issue is that the animation proceeds linearly and doesn't follow the curved path of the outer circle. And I can't think of any concept to implement the pendulum collision.

Comment: Interesting idea. How far have you gotten on your own?  Or are you expecting an answer with the complete solution?

Comment: @cricket_007 : check my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sample code needs some adjustments, but I believe it will help you:

```
package com.pachacuti.bouncingball;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int windowHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        int windowWidth =  displayMetrics.widthPixels;

        final RotateAnimation rAnimLeft1 = new RotateAnimation(0, 90,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, windowWidth/2, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0);
        rAnimLeft1.setDuration(4000);

        final RotateAnimation rAnimLeft2 = new RotateAnimation(0, -180,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, windowWidth/2, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0);
        rAnimLeft2.setDuration(4000);
        rAnimLeft2.setRepeatCount(-1);
        rAnimLeft2.setRepeatMode(2);

        final RotateAnimation rAnimRight1 = new RotateAnimation(0, -90,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, -windowWidth/2, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0);
        rAnimRight1.setDuration(4000);

        final RotateAnimation rAnimRight2 = new RotateAnimation(0, 180,
                Animation.ABSOLUTE, -windowWidth/2, Animation.ABSOLUTE, 0);
        rAnimRight2.setDuration(4000);
        rAnimRight2.setRepeatCount(-1);
        rAnimRight2.setRepeatMode(2);

        final View bleft = findViewById(R.id.bLeft);
        AnimationSet animSetLeft = new AnimationSet(true);
        animSetLeft.addAnimation(rAnimLeft1);
        animSetLeft.addAnimation(rAnimLeft2);
        bleft.startAnimation(animSetLeft);

        final View bright = findViewById(R.id.bRight);
        AnimationSet animSetRight = new AnimationSet(true);
        animSetRight.addAnimation(rAnimRight1);
        animSetRight.addAnimation(rAnimRight2);
        bright.startAnimation(animSetRight);
    }

}
```

And the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.moahh.bouncingball.MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bLeft"
        android:layout_width="10px"
        android:layout_height="10px"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bRight"
        android:layout_width="10px"
        android:layout_height="10px"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```